# How to model Players for different Sports in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am building an app that have the following requirements:

> -> A User can be a player of different teams.
>   -> A Team can be of a sport type.

My question is:

> -> Since for each sport type I want to store different information of a Player, what would be the best way to model that?

I have thought on having several models (and tables) for each kind of Sport, for example:

Basketball_Players, Football_Players and so on, but I am not sure if that would be a good approach.  How do you usually do this on RoR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you have two options, and I don't know that it's really possible to say which is the "most correct" way to do it without knowing the details of the requirements of your application.

What's a given is that you'll have a `sport` table and a `player` table. I can say that for sure. The question is how you connect the two.

**Option 1: a single join table**

You could have a table called `player_sport` (or whatever) with a `player_id` column, a `sport_id` column, and a `serialized_player_data` column or something like that, where you'd keep serialized player data (JSON, perhaps) depending on the sport. **Pros:** simple schema. **Cons:** not properly normalized, and therefore subject to inconsistencies.

**Option 2: a separate join table for each sport**

This is what you alluded to in your question, where you have a `basketball_player`, `football_player`, etc. Here you'd also have a `player_id` column but probably not a `sport_id` column because that would be redundant now that you're specifying the sport right in the table name. The need to have a `serialized_player_data` column would go away, since you'd now be free to store the needed attributes directly in columns, e.g. `wrestling_player.weight_class_id` or whatever. **Pros:** proper normalization. **Cons:** more complex schema, and therefore more work in your application code.

There's actually a third option as well:

**Option 3: a combination of 1 and 2**

Here you might do everything you would do in Option 2, except you'd move the common player attributes to the `player_sport` table and save `basketball_player`, etc. for the sport-specific attributes. So `weight_class_id` would stay in `wrestling_player` but `player_sport` would have `height`, `weight`, and other columns that are relevant to all sports.

**If you're looking for a recommendation, I would probably do Option 2, or, if it looks like there's enough overlap for it to make sense, Option 3.**

Comment: Jason thanks for the answer. I have a question though.  What would be the relation between "Team" and "Players". I mean, if I have a model called Team, would I need to have assocations such as "has_many soccer_players, has_many basketball_players..." ? How would you do it?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't just have a `player_team` table with a `team_id` and `player_id`. The `team` table would have a `sport_id`; no need, as far as I can tell, for `player_team` to know which sport it's for.

Comment: I'm actually leaning increasingly toward option 1, or option 3. It's not an easy thing to model!